# When to use a substring to pass to a method vs passing whole string and using integers to specify boundary

Tags: java, string

Say you have a string where you are part way processing it but you ran into a part that is to be handled by a different method. Is it better to pass the entire string and use `int`s to show the boundaries or should a substring be created and passed as the argument to the other method?

The use is for a method that is processing an expression but if brackets are encountered another method is called.

So for example say I have a method `process (String str)`. In it there's a line `if(str.charAt(i) == '(')` that calls another method that is responsible for finding the closing bracket. Would it be better to  pass the method str.substring(i, str.length) or just have the method take a second parameter and pass it *i* so it knows where to start working from?

Comment: What do you mean by boundaries?

Comment: Can you give an example string for your case ?

Comment: opinion: for processing an expression, I'd go with integer boundaries, which might make it easier to produce debugging information--the methods will know which character position relative to the entire input that it's dealing with

Answer (score 0):

Because string are immutable. When you call subString on a instance you create new object. So in case of performance is better to pass the whole String and the indexes of start and end, but instead passing the String you may want to pass char[].

In Java 7 you can use class [Segment](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Segment.html) for representation.

You could also use the [CharSequence](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/CharSequence.html) as attribute for methods. This will assure that you will not mutate the object and still have the flexibility of array of chars.

Comment: Why would using CharSequence be better?

Comment: @Celeritas I have edited the answer. If you have any comment please fell free to ask.

Comment: Why would String.substring make a copy of the substring? The whole point of immutability is that you can pass around such a substring with no danger to the original.

Comment: Though, looking in the jdk source code it appears you are right.

Comment: @ThomasAhle If I remember correctly it's to prevent memory leaks from small substrings preventing the `char[]` from large source strings being GC'd. The change occurred in Java 7, I believe.